# Please help me understand why asking about an acid-base reaction was down-voted and closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, down-votes

I am new to Chemistry on SE and was DV'd several times and closed for this question:

- [What results from the neutralization copper citrate with Na2CO3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172298/what-results-from-the-neutralization-copper-citrate-with-na2co3)

It seems on-topic, but I must be missing something.

The question started far too broad, so I edited it down to a much simpler question, but it was downvoted again and ultimately closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears the focus of your question shifted between edits from how to dispose of a particular mixture ("How should a Copper Citrate solution be prepared for disposal down the drain?") to identifying the product of a chemical protocol ("What results from the neutralization copper citrate with Na2CO3"). During that time, different people may have identified different aspects of the question they found required editing, and the history reflects that. For instance, there was a mistake in chemical notation later (sodium carbonate formula). An edit does not automatically reset the number of close votes.  Whether the response as a whole is fully justified is not clear.

Note you removed information. Less detail is usually worse than more, unless it's stuff frowned upon such as [personal medical questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) or homeworkish questions [and the like](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If in doubt of what information to include write a terse summary of your question at the beginning and follow that with a more detailed explanation.

Regarding downvotes in general, they are anonymous. Different users have different quality standards although the links above lead to general guidelines that all should try to follow. Individuals may provide commentary but the site has no rules that they must.